# select datetime with strtotime()

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, datetime

i want to select data which has a type datetime in mssql with php. I tried this code:

```
 $date = strtotime($row['DateTime']);
       echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

it returns this error strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string.

if i tried to convert string this DateTime it returns DateTime can not convert to string.

Can you explain what is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You already get a native PHP date object from the SQLSRV driver. You don't need to convert anything!

Whenever you need to print it, just use the [DateTime::format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method:

```
echo $row['DateTime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: i thought i have to convert to string. thanks for help.

Comment: Yeah, that's what `DateTime can not convert to string` was trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

try with `datetime()`

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-06-29 12:00:00'); //$row['DateTime']
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or use directly format your date row

For more read manual :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

or may be it's already converted in correct date format so try

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['DateTime']);
```